# Dynamic proxy_pass to $var with nginx 1.0

Tags: proxy, nginx

I am trying to proxy a request to different targets depending on an environment variable. My approach was to put the target url into the custom variable $target and give this to proxy_pass.

But using a variable with proxy_pass doesn't seem to work. This simple config leads to a "502 Bad Gateway" response from nginx.

```
server {
  listen   8080;
  server_name  myhost.example.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/myhost.access.log;
  location /proxy {
    set $target http://proxytarget.example.com;
    proxy_pass $target;
  }
}
```

The same config without the variable works:

```
server {
  listen   8080;
  server_name  myhost.example.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/myhost.access.log;
  location /proxy {
    proxy_pass http://proxytarget.example.com;
  }
}
```

Is it really not possible to use proxy_pass this way or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I've recently stumbled upon this need myself and have found that in order to use variables in a proxy_pass destination you need to set a resolver as your error.log would most probably contain something like  `no resolver defined to resolve ...`

The solution in my case was to setup the following using a local DNS for DNS resolution:

```
location ~ /proxy/(.*) {
    resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1];
    proxy_pass http://$1;
}
```

In your case this should work:

```
location /proxy {
    resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1];
    set $target http://proxytarget.example.com;
    proxy_pass $target;
}
```

For resolver 127.0.0.1 to work, you need to install bind9 locally.
For Debian/Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install bind9

More information on nginx and dynamic `proxy_pass`ing here: http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html

Edit:
Replaced the previous public DNS with a local one for security [issues](http://blog.zorinaq.com/nginx-resolver-vulns/).

Comment: FYI, Nginx does not use /etc/hosts, with or without resolver: http://serverfault.com/questions/357719/nginx-domain-resolver

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I set an variable, but it seems that nginx can't resolve it if used in proxy_pass directive. In proxy_redirect the same variable works as expected.

Comment: Do **NOT** use a publicly accessible DNS server such as `8.8.8.8`. [To prevent DNS spoofing, it is recommended configuring DNS servers in a properly secured trusted local network.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver)

Comment: Resolver is required for fully-qualifed domain names, NOT variables. If the variable you're passing contains an IP address, it works fine.

Comment: For anyone using Kubernetes you can use the internal Kube DNS service: `resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326913/nginx-proxy-pass-directive-string-interpolation/43341304#43341304

Comment: Use **127.0.0.1 [::1]** instead of **8.8.8.8** to prevent DNS spoofing. You also need to install **bind9** "sudo apt-get install bind9" for Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: This pattern ~ /proxy/(.*) doesn't seem to match query string

Comment: You made my day ! Thanks

Comment: I understand Nginx has its own mechanism to resolve a domain, but it doesn't explain why `proxy_pass http://proxytarget.example.com` works.

Answer (score 30):

Even though the answer of @soulseekah is complete and correct I want to post an answer for the folks using Nginx inside a cluster of containers, being those inside Kubernetes or Docker Compose.

Basically you have to configure a resolver for Nginx with the address of your actual DNS resolver. For Docker it is [always](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) at `127.0.0.11`, for Kubernetes refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43341304/3482533)

Inside my docker network I was able to successfully configure a dynamic `proxy_pass` by doing so:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 [::1];
set $bcknd http://$http_XBackend$uri$is_args$args;
proxy_pass        $bcknd;
```

Note that it [was fundamental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/how-can-query-string-parameters-be-forwarded-through-a-proxy-pass-with-nginx) to add the `$uri$is_args$args` since otherwise the proxy pass didn't take in consideration the path and the query string.

PS: in my example, I am reading an header using the `$http_XBackend` variable. The header is passed by the client as `XBackend: host`, here the `host` should be the hostname where you want to forward your calls. I tried using headers with dashes in them with no luck, I had to use an header without dashes.

---

Edit 16 Jul 2020: Docker doesn't report any more on their webpage the address for the default DNS server. It is still 127.0.0.11:53. If you want to see this value inside your container you need to run `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I'll add a commentary here: Seems like the '127.0.0.11' DNS server is only available for user defined networks, not for default networks, so I'd be wary on using it unless checked working before :P :D

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on the same exact issue

proxy_pass wasn't resolving my variables, until we found out our DNS server had a problem

can be checked with this cmd  by the way

```
nslookup your-domain your-dns-ip
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 location / {
   if ($args ~ "^url=(.+)") { #gets the "url" get parameter
       set $key1 $1;
     proxy_pass $key1;#use the parameter as proxy address
 }
}
```