# Nginx proxy_pass having problems with querystring for an API

Tags: api, nginx

I'm trying to proxy a certain rest endpoint on my linux api box to my windows box.  Here's what I have right now.

My linux api box

```
...
location ~ ^/api/v0/roslyn(.*)$ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass $scheme://my-windows-box.com/roslyn$1;
}
```

For example, I'd like to proxy the following url

```
http://my-linux-box.com/api/v0/roslyn?q=5
```

to

```
http://my-windows-box.com/roslyn?q=5
```

However, it seems to be missing the querystring, so the regex is failing?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/with-nginx-how-to-forward-query-parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can match the args by regex, try this instead

```
location /api/v0/roslyn {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass $scheme://my-windows-box.com/roslyn$is_args$query_string;
}
```