# Reverse proxy not passing query string to application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-location

I created a rails app that is deployed into a subdirectory of my Vultr server. Somehow, no GET parameters are considered by the backend. For example, calls from the [ForestAdmin API](https://www.forestadmin.com/) don't read GET parameters ([see issue here](https://community.forestadmin.com/t/search-and-filters-arent-working/879)). Also, my search page is not receiving GET parameters, example for [this search query](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/recherche?q=test) in production, I get the following logs:

[image: logs]

As you can see, in the title, the « » is blank as it should display the q parameter.

My Rails app config seems right, so I guess it's a server configuration issue.

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    scope 'dictionnaire' do
        mount ForestLiana::Engine => '/forest'
        root to: "home#index"
        resources :words, path: "definition", param: :slug

        post '/search', to: 'words#search'
        get '/recherche', to: 'words#search_page', as: 'recherche'
        get '/:letter', to: 'words#alphabet_page', param: :letter, as: "alphabetic_page"

        post '/api/get_synonyms', to: 'api#get_synonyms'
    end
    
end
```

And here is my nginx config:

```
location @ruby-app {
#    rewrite ^/dictionnaire-app(.*) $1 break;
    rewrite ^/dictionnaire$ /dictionnaire/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/dictionnaire/definition-(.*) /dictionnaire/definition/$1 permanent;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$uri;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}

location ~ /dictionnaire(.*)$ {    
    alias /opt/dictionnaire-app/public;
    try_files $1 @ruby-app;
}
```

and

```
location /dictionnaire {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dictionnaire/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Any idea what could be the issue preventing the parameters from being passed?

Comment: how are you running the rails server, using puma or unicorn or any other?

Comment: What to rails logs show? If you do `tail -f log/development.log | grep -A 5 'Started'`, do the log statements there include the params? 

If not, what do the nginx logs show? `sudo tail -f var/log/nginx/access.log | grep ... `

Comment: Please add example request.

Comment: The rails server is using Puma. I added an example request with the logs in the question. @NavedKhan there is no access.log into the nginx directory, but nginx error logs for the website doesn't show any error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

proxy_pass is not forwarding query strings to rails application

## Solution

Add `$is_args` to your proxy pass statement. This includes either empty string or “?” depending on presence query string in request.

Add `$args` or `$query_string` to your proxy pass statement. This appends the query string to your proxied request.

### Example

Instead of:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$uri;
```

Do:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$uri$is_args$args;
```

## References

Nginx http core module (navigate to embedded variables): http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8130872/806876