# Links in Parse Server emails are broken (validate account, reset password...)

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I try to install a Parse server on my local server (Ubuntu 20.04).

All features works fine... except one: the email system (for reset password or validate email address for example). I installed an adapter and the emails are sent, but the link they contain is broken: when I click on it I am redirected to an "Invalid link" page. After few hours of investigation, I don't understand what happen.

Here are my configuration files:

- First, I use Nginx as a proxy, here is the part of my config file for my domain name which concern my Parse server:

```
     location ~ ^/parse/(.*)$ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/$1;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }
         location /parsedashboard {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4040;
            }
        
            location /login {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4040/login;
            }
        
            location /bundles {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4040/bundles;
            }
        
            location ~ ^/apps(.*)$ {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4040/apps$1;
            }
```

- Here is my Parse config.js file :

```
    {
      "appName": "App name - Parse Server",
      "logsFolder": "/var/www/my/app/logs/",
      "databaseURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/parsedb",
      "appId": "my_app_id",
      "masterKey": "my_master_key",
      "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      "publicServerURL": "https://my_domain.ovh/parse",
      "port": 1337,
      "cloud": "/var/www/my/app/cloud/main.js",
      "push": {
          "android": {
                "apiKey": "my_api_key"
          }
      },
      "liveQuery": {
        "classNames":["Class_1", "Class_2", "Class_3"]
      },
      "verifyUserEmails": true,
      "emailAdapter": {
        "module": "parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template",
        "options": {
          "fromAddress": "My app ",
          "domain": "my_domain.mailgun.org",
          "apiKey": "my-api-key"
        }
      }
     }
```

The links which are contained in e-mails seems good, for example:

`https://my_domain.ovh/parse/apps/APP_ID/request_password_reset?token=TOKEN&username=juju`

But as I said, it redirects to an "Invalid link" page.

I tried to understand why this redirection happens by adding some log in parse-server/lib/Routers/PublicAPIRouter.js, in requestResetPassword(req) method and I saw that username and token got from query are empty:

```
     const {
          username,
          token: rawToken
        } = req.query;
        const token = rawToken && typeof rawToken !== 'string' ? rawToken.toString() : rawToken;
    
        if (!username || !token) {
                _logger.default.info("  - usn : " + (!username) + ", token : " + (!token));
          return this.invalidLink(req);
        }
```

I have the log: "  - usn : true, token : true"

I'm not a expert in NodeJS (euphemism ^^) so I don't really know how to continue my investigations.

Do you have an idea of the cause of this problem?
*(For information, all others features of my Parse server work fine: database access, cloud code, live query, dashboard...)*

Thank you in advance :)

Julien

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks to *davimacedo* from Parse community forum :)

The problem was a wrong configuration of nginx reverse proxy: request parameters was not forward to the Parse server.

Details can be found in this thread:
[How can query string parameters be forwarded through a proxy_pass with nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/how-can-query-string-parameters-be-forwarded-through-a-proxy-pass-with-nginx)

For my configuration, this means simply add **$is_args$args** at the end of the “proxy_pass” line. The complete line is:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337/parse/$1$is_args$args;
```

After this, all works as expected \o/