# next/image went missing when deployed to AWS (Next.js)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js, nextjs-image

Folder structure as below:

```
|-root
  |-pages
    |-_app.tsx
    |-index.tsx
  |-public
    |-logo.svg
    |-image.png
    |-image2.png
    |-image3.png
```

When I run `yarn build` and `yarn start` in localhost, my image files can be found in the following locations:

[image]

Everything works fine if I deploy it via Vercel. However, when I tried to deploy on AWS(ECR image), only SVG files were found. Error showing

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`

Also it shows `"url" parameter is required` when I click those image URL.

[image]

Could you please let me know what the issue is?

Edit: PNG files aren't created when deployed to AWS
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that it was a configuration issue with Nginx.

As Nextjs Image component will send the image source path with the size through url query string, so

1. Accept parameters must be set for Nginx

```
  location ~* ^/(.*) {
    proxy_pass  http://service_url/$1$is_args$args;
  }
```

[How can query string parameters be forwarded through a proxy_pass with nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/)

2. Make sure cloudfront behavior not to ignore the query string
   [image]

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25121