# Nginx proxy_pass with variables and redirect

Tags: nginx

It seems that Nginx can't support redirects when proxy_pass is set to variable. Is there a way to achieve this functionality e.g. somehow chain servers or other workaround? What is the reason why this is not supported?

.conf is:

```
proxy_pass $var;
proxy_redirect  default;
```

Error message I get is:

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_redirect default" cannot be used with "proxy_pass" directive with  variables

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this problem by specifying the full redirect statement instead of using the "default" option.

From the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect):

> The default replacement specified by the default parameter uses the parameters of the location and proxy_pass directives. Hence, the two configurations below are equivalent:
>
> ```
> location /one/ {
>     proxy_pass     http://upstream:port/two/;
>     proxy_redirect default;
> location /one/ {
>     proxy_pass     http://upstream:port/two/;
>     proxy_redirect http://upstream:port/two/ /one/;
> ```

So to replace the "default" directive, you use the value of "proxy_pass" as the first argument for "proxy_redirect", and use the value of "location" for the second.

Answer (score -2):

I once had the same issue and what saved me was Nginx's resolver module

try to add:

```
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

before the proxy_pass line. It should allow you to work with variables.

Also [have a look at a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743609/dynamic-proxy-pass-to-var-with-nginx-1-0).

Comment: This is totally different problem, I have resolver configured yes of course.