# Nginx pass_proxy with variables

Tags: nginx, url

I'm having trouble making nginx proxy an url with variable to a service within kubernetes.
Url looks like this:
`http://localhost/user?username=Dave`
I expect this url to take me to a subpage `/user`, which will read `?username=Dave` and then fetch data from a database. However this takes me to the home page of the application(`/` instead of `/user`) and does not read the variable even though url includes `/user?username=Dave`.
My current nginx config file looks like this:

```
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name localhost;

location / {
  proxy_pass http://${FLASK_APP}:8080/;
}
location /user {
      proxy_pass http://${GO_APP}:8000/;
  }
}
```

I have read that `location /user` will match the url I'm passing. What is wrong with it? Or do I need to add something to `proxy_pass http://${GO_APP}:8000/;` or `location /user`?

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326913/nginx-proxy-pass-directive-string-interpolation/43341304#43341304

Comment: I'm not sure how that thread is related to my question?

Comment: Well you state it "doesn't work." Without an indication, such as an error, not much else to go on. That question looks similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Updated my question. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: What does this mean? "this directs me to the home page of the GO_APP and does not even though url includes /user?username=Dave" I feel your question would be better received if you put it in an actual vs. expected format.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add more information again. Hope it's clearer this time.

Comment: I see now, have you tried `proxy_pass http://${GO_APP}:8000/user/;`? You may also need to do `proxy_pass http://${GO_APP}:8000/user$is_args;` to get the query string.

Comment: I did and still the same. I changed it to `http://${GO_APP}:8000/user?$args;` and while it gets me to the correct page it still doesn't read the variable from the url.

Comment: Ok I see the problem, this is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/how-can-query-string-parameters-be-forwarded-through-a-proxy-pass-with-nginx) that relates to it. This comes from your using `${GO_APP}` in the `proxy_pass` URI.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. I'm trying this `location ~* /user?(.*)$ {
      proxy_pass http://${GO_APP}:8000/user?$1$args;
  }` and now I'm getting bad gateway.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the issue arises because you are using a variable in the `proxy_pass` target. As also noted in the comments, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130692/how-can-query-string-parameters-be-forwarded-through-a-proxy-pass-with-nginx) is related. As the answer referencing the docs states:

> A special case is using variables in the proxy_pass statement: The
>   requested URL is not used and you are fully responsible to construct
>   the target URL yourself.

This means that you either need to use a static `proxy_pass` target, such as

```
// note that I added the forward slash
location /user/ {
    proxy_pass http://destination:8000/;
}
```

Or as an alternative, I believe you can do it this way also

```
location /user/ {
    proxy_pass http://${GO_APP}:8000/user$is_args$args;
}
```