# Nginx rewrite with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I recently have a requirement in Nginx to rewrite a URL and then forward this onto to another backend server to a dynamic proxy pass address. I've tried a few things but have not had much luck at the moment. For example, this is the kind of setup I have in my nginx.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name scheduler.domain-name;
  rewrite ^scheduler(.*)/(.*)/(.*) $2$1$3; # scheduler.domain.local/changepass/report?target=service
...

location / {
  proxy_pass $to-rewrite-address:9443; # changepass.domain.local/report?target=service
  ...
}
```

Essentially, I just need to use a re-written URL variable to forward the request on a different port but can't seen to get this to work.

I've done quite a bit of searching but haven't found the solution to this as of yet, though I understand that the DNS resolver has to be set when using a proxy pass variable ([Dynamic proxy_pass to $var with nginx 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743609/dynamic-proxy-pass-to-var-with-nginx-1-0)).

Grateful if anyone could advise on how the above could be achieved, many thanks.

Comment: `rewrite` directive works with normalized URI (`/changepass/report` in your example), it does not work with domain name or query arguments.

Comment: This particular example should work with something like `location /changepass/ { proxy_pass http://changepass.domain.local:9443/; }`. It would be better if you provide more details to your question about your possible endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently there are only a couple of endpoints but in the future there will be a lot more. The hope was that we could just use the rewrite directive to handle this without ever having to add additional proxy_pass directives in Nginx as each one becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your endpoint would always be specified as the first part of your URI, here is an example of configuration that should work:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name scheduler.domain-name;
    resolver <your resolver for domain.local>;
    ...
    location ~ ^/(?<endpoint>changepass|endpoint2|endpoint3|...)(?<route>/.*) {
        proxy_pass http://$endpoint.domain.local:9443$route;
    }
}
```

I'm using named capturing groups here for a better readibility, this location block is equal to

```
    location ~ ^/(changepass|endpoint2|endpoint3|...)(/.*) {
        proxy_pass http://$1.domain.local:9443$2;
    }
```

I'm not sure if query arguments would be preserved with such a construction, if they won't, change

```
proxy_pass http://$endpoint.domain.local:9443$route;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://$endpoint.domain.local:9443$route$is_args$args;
```

Comment: Will try this out, really appreciate the response.

Comment: @DanielCampailla Please give some feedback whet you test this, I'm especially interested if first `proxy_pass` preserves the query arguments or you need to use the second one with `$is_args$args`.