# How can I make NGINX reverse proxy conditional on HTTP header value

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have reverse proxy like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location = /my-proxy {
      proxy_pass https://somehost/v1
    }
}
```

Now I would like to pass it to /v2 if HTTP request header `x-version-toggle` is set to `v2`, something like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location = /my-proxy {
      if ($http-x-version-toggle == 'v2') {
        proxy_pass https://somehost/v2
      }
      proxy_pass https://somehost/v1
    }
}
```

What is the precise syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` operator provided by nginx

```
map $http_x_version_toggle $backend {
        default http://10.41.115.241:8000/; 
        v2 http://127.0.0.1:9101/;
}
```

And then in the location use it as below

```
proxy_pass $backend
```

Comment: This is incomplete, for using `proxy_pass` with variables you also need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743609/dynamic-proxy-pass-to-var-with-nginx-1-0